# Convergence of a sum involving the divisor function and characters

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Could someone please show me that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \sigma_{x}(n)n^{-(x + 1)/2} \chi(n)$ converges where $\chi $ is a Dirichlet character of modulus $m$?

Comment: For what $x$ are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in -1 < x < 1.